# Firefox not expanding absolute positioned div containing buttons

Tags: css, firefox, button, styling

I have two divs, both positioned absolute, one inside the other, serving as a menu. In the inner one I have some button elements that should expand the parent div. Fine in theory, Chrome and IE. But I cant get it to work in Firefox. The buttons dont expand the parent div.

Oddly it works if I add an extra a tag element after the buttons.

## Css

```
/* .Menu-Wrapper and .Menu have to have postion: absolute */

.Menu-Wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 100px;
}
.Menu {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 6px;
}
.Menu-item {
    background: red;
    border: 0;
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: left;
}
```

## html

```
<div class="Menu-Wrapper">
        <!-- there would be a trigger button here, left out for simplicity -->
    <div class="Menu">
        <!-- in firefox the follwoing buttons do not expand to width text -->
        <button class="Menu-item">Menu Point 1 ....</button>
        <button class="Menu-item">Menu Point 1</button>
        <button class="Menu-item">Menu Point 1..</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

## See Example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/2Xbpq/ (not working in Firefox)

Any idea how to make it work in Firefox?

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding why .Menu needs to be absolutely positioned?  From the code I see its just a container for the .Menu-items.

Comment: In the "real" code there is a trigger element inside .Menu-Wrapper which would only show Menu when clicked. Therefore Menu needs to be absolute positioned. And Menu-Wrapper is absolutely positioned, so I can move it around freely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`width: -moz-available;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2Fwidth#compat-desktop)

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xbpq/4/)

It'll fix it, though I'm not quite sure why ff is acting strange in this context ..

Comment: wow, thx. how did you come up with that one, I tried some -moz prefixes, but not this one, thx alot, wasted a good amount of time on this one.